# "Unable to Verify App" message started to appear for an already existing iOS app

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an app being deployed to QA ad hoc. All the builds have always been signed with the same provisioning profile under the same developer account. In the last two weeks, I built two different versions (e.g. 0.0.2 and 0.0.3). So, QA had been working with version 0.0.2 until last Wednesday, when 0.0.3 was ready. The new build was signed in exactly the same way as before. However, on a test device with iOS 16.3.1 it did not start, showing the following message:

[image: Unable to verify app]

(Note: Everything was OK with Internet connection there, as QA tried to run the app immediately after downloading it and also tried it dozens of times later on)

NB1: After the problem appeared, QA checked the previous version (0.0.2), and it still ran fine on the target device. However, the issue persisted when returning to 0.0.3.
NB2: The app does not appear in Settings/General/VPN&Device management section, so there is no way to actually verify it.
NB3: The same IPA file runs on iOS 12 and 14 without any issues all the time.

I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could clarify the reasons of such behaviour or at least point out how to avoid it in future.

**PS**:
In my case, **the only remedy was time** (curses on the heads of Apple staff!) - after several days things came to order on their own.

Comment: You're not alone : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736905.
I did not find any solution yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

We are not seeing this issue anymore with devices updated to iOS 17.3+

Apple probably silently fixed the problem.